# Why won't my ExpressJS server accept POST requests?

Tags: post, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Configuration

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

// Routes

app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.headers);
  res.end();
});

app.listen(1234);
```

When I load `http://localhost:1234` in a browser, it works as expected and I Get the following output:

```
{ host: 'localhost:1234',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:6.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/6.0.2',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
  'accept-language': 'en-us,en;q=0.5',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
  connection: 'keep-alive' }
```

But when I post data, it doesn't return anything. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `app.get`. That will only respond to `GET` requests. You might want to see if `app.post` works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a catchall route:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res){
  res.send(200, req.route.method+' '+req.originalUrl);
});
```

Remember that the order you invoke `app.method(route...)` matters. If you put that catchall route at the top of your routing code, it will match every single request. Since it always sends a response, any matching routes further down won't be executed.

If you want to skip a particular routing function and continue to any subsequent matching routes, you can pass and invoke a `next` callback in the routing function:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  console.log(req.route.method+' '+req.originalUrl);
  next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(500);
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
  res.send(404);
});
```